# Does C++ have interface class concept and if it is there then how it differ from java interface class?

Tags: java, c++, class, interface

In some of the design patterns, it is advised to write an interface class and the examples are given in Java. How to write an interface class in C++?

Answer (score 3):

That is a really broad question. There are only classes in C++, and it depends on the methods you give them whether they will be abstract.

The best fit in C++ for a Java interface is a class which has no data members and only public pure virtual methods, meaning there is a `= 0` at the end of their declaration.

A class is abstract when it can't be instantiated. A class can't be instantiated when it has at least one pure virtual function. So an interface, according to the previous definition, is a special case of an abstract class in C++.

C++ classes can be derived from any number of base classes, but just like in Java, C++ programmers usually derive from only one base class which actually has implementations for its methods. (Note that pure virtual functions may have implementations, defined outside of the class in a source file, but that's an uncommon edge case.)

Answer (score 0):

c++ doesn't have interfaces, and java doesn't have multiple inheritance.

Comment: it does since java 8

Comment: @RayTayek What??? No.

Comment: @RayTayek If you mean default methods then no, it's not multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Oleg Well, then upvote

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán Thanks, not a deserved one. I'm annoyed by the discussion here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365208/1398418 so I'm somewhat trolling.